# Как разрешить PUT запрос на сервер?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, rest, iis-express

В [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) есть контроллер:

```
[RouteArea("api")]
[RoutePrefix("assemblies")]
public class AssemblyController: Controller
{
    [Route(), HttpPut]
    public ActionResult EditAssembly(AssemblyViewModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK) ;
        }
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) ;
    }
}
```

На клиенте использую [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) версии 1.5.8, запрос на сервер отправляю так:

```
function(assembly){
    let url = '/api/assemblies/';
    return $http.put(url, {model: assembly})
}
```

на что получаю следующий ответ:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Поиск в интернете показал что данная ошибка связана с тем что необходимо разрешить на сервере `PUT` запрос.

Что пробовал сделать:

разрешить соответствующие запросы как советуют [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7064250/5610621) и не только,

т.е. в файл конфигурации [iis-express](/questions/tagged/iis-express) я внес необходимые изменения:

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE"
```

**не помогло.**

WebDAV модуль не установлен.
Visual Studio 2015 Community

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33278362/5610621

Answer (score 1):

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Добавление выше приведенных строк в `web.congig` позволяет выполнять `put/delete` запросы к серверу. решение было найдено [здесь](http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/rest-http-verbs-and-iis-express)

---

**Update**:

решение не работает в случае использования стандартного атрибута `[Authorize]`, в этом случае сервер отдает следующую ошибку:

> **HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized**
>
> *Этот прошедший проверку пользователь не имеет доступа к ресурсу, необходимому для выполнения обработки запроса.*

в тоже время `post` запрос выполняется без проблем.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

решение было найдено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33278362/5610621)

Comment: А [Authorize] - то тут при чем? В каком виде запрос приходит на сервер?

Comment: @PavelMayorov если у контроллера убрать данный атрибут, то тогда я попадаю в метод, иначе указанная мной ошибка

Comment: *В каком виде запрос приходит на сервер?*

Comment: @PavelMayorov не совсем понял Ваш вопрос: на сервер запрос отправляю средставами ангуляра: `$http.put(url)`

Comment: Блин, запрос как выглядит? Какие у него заголовки?

Comment: @PavelMayorov давайте продолжим обсуждение в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57454/room-for-bald-and-pavel-mayorov)